# How use a jQuery selector to find all matching elements withing a given div?

Tags: jquery, selector

I know how to find all elements of the document with the id `id1` with jQuery: `$("#id1")`.

Is there a similar way to find all the elements within a given div with the id `id1`?

Comment: What?? You need to make this clearer...

Comment: what is "test" div is a ID ? of parent div ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find #id1 only if it's inside of #test, then you can use this:

```
$("#test #id1")
```

or this:

```
$("#test").find("#id1")
```

These are structurally identical.  In fact, the first one ends up doing basically the same thing as the second one internally.

Keep in mind that you can only have once occurrence of any id value in a given document, but there are sometimes when you only want to find `#id1` if it's in `#test` and this would do that for you.

If you just want #id1, then you don't need to bound the scope (since there can only be one) so you can just do this which is also a lot faster:

```
$("#id1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your test div has the id "test",

You can do

```
$("#test #id1")
```

or

```
$('#test').find("#id1")
```

But both don't really make sense as you must have **only one** element with a given id in a document. So, assuming your document is correct,  both are equivalent to `$("#id1")`.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting an element by id, the id selector performs well enough that `$('#id')` is generally all you need. If you already have a reference to the `#test` `<div>` stored in a variable though, it is possible to [provide a context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) to the jQuery selector, which will reduce the work done by the search.

Note that this is only useful if you *already have the reference to* `#test`, otherwise you end up doing two searches.

Usage:

```
var $testDiv = $('#test');
// ...
var $id1Div = $('#id1', $testDiv)
```

As mentioned in the link, it is computationally equivalent to doing:

```
$testDiv.find('#id1')
```

Since html IDs are unique, and the search is implemented with the browser's native `document.getElementById`, providing the context isn't particularly useful here. But for other selectors, it can be very useful.